# What is the scope of a for loop without braces in C++

Tags: c++, scope, curly-braces

I understand that `{...}` introduces a new scope, which is why the following would not work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Do something...
}

cout << i << endl;  // Error: i is not defined in this scope
```

However, I'm getting the same error when I try the same thing without braces.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) continue;
cout << i << endl;  // Same error, not sure why
```

I expected `i` to be defined in the 2nd example, because there are no `{...}` to introduce a new scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any control structure (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc.) without braces applies *only to the next statement*. The second example is equivalent to the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    continue;
}
cout << i << endl;
```

Note that it's often considered bad style to have control structures without braces, because people can forget to add the braces if they add another line, and it can lead to the [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.

Comment: Does that have anything to do with the fact that {} also has its own scope (not necessarily in control structures)?

Comment: @AbrahamMurcianoBenzadon — no. Note that the definition of `I` is **not** inside the curly braces. The rule is essentially what this answer says: the scope of a variable defined in a control structure ends at the end of the controlled statement. The controlled statement can be a simple statement or it can be a compound statement enclosed in curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

The scope for the visibility of `i` is the `for()` loops body.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) continue;
```

is just equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { continue; }
```

If the braces are omitted, the body is just the statement following the `for()` loop header.